# Azure YAML pipeline to copy files from repo to multiple linux host

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to set a pipeline to copy files from azure repo to 5 linux nodes' used copy files overssh task which asks for an endpoint where we can enter single host .hence I am using installssh task to set up ssh key but somehow when I pass a script , I am not able to reach the remote host. is there anyway other way to perform copy files to multiple Linux servers?
below is the code :

```
  -task: InstallSSHKey@0

   inputs:

    knownHostsEntry: known hosts
    sshPublicKey:
    sshKeySecureFile: 'private key'

  -script: |
     ssh ubuntu@3.86.228.255 | pwd
```

Comment: Can you ping the machine 3.86.228.255? Is it accessible through internet? Is there any firewall blocking the connection through ssh? Also what is your error output?

Comment: m- task: InstallSSHKey@0
  inputs:
    knownHostsEntry: 'hosts"
    sshPublicKey: 'public key'
    sshKeySecureFile: 'secure pvt key'
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
        # Write your commands here
        
        ssh ubuntu@servername | ls

Comment: when i exectue above code
below is the output of bash 
/usr/bin/bash /home/vsts/work/_temp/d1ee5124-3499-412a-9b7f-80ec601d1bf7.sh
README.md
Template.yml
azure-pipelines-1.yml
azure-pipelines-2.yml
azure-pipelines-3.yml
azure-pipelines-4.yml
azure-pipelines-5.yml
azure-pipelines.yml
demo.yml
powershelldemo.ps1

Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.

Warning: Permanently added 'remote host' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.


"The "ls" lists my files in my repo rather listing files or directories in my remote server"